# How can I transfer a custom keyboard layout from one computer to another?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, transfer

I use two languages regularly (English and Bengali) and I have a custom keyboard layout to type Bengali which a friend made for me, (on my Windows 7 machine). I have just gotten a new computer (windows 10) and I want to use the same keyboard. Can someone please tell me how to transfer that same keyboard onto my new computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Layout definitions are saved in Layout DLL files. These files reside in the Windows's standard System32 directory.](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/admin_deploy.html#:%7E:text=Layout%20definitions%20are%20saved%20in,kbd%2C%20and%20have%20the%20standard%20.)

If you don't know the DLL filename of your keyboard then get [Keyboard Layout Manager](https://keyboard-layout-manager.software.informer.com/) on the computer you wish to copy the layout from. The program displays the keyboard name and DLL filename.

Copy that DLL from Windows/System32 and Windows/SysWOW64, and paste on the new computer.

Then it should be in the registry. Copy the following in a text file and save with ".reg" extension. (Also you can export the entry from your old computer):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\A0030409]
"Layout File"="yourdllfile.dll"
"Layout Text"="Pirate Language"
"layout id"="00C7"
```

The Layout File and Layout Text should match yours.
The folder name and layout id, I think can be any not already in use.
Execute it afterwards and you're done.

The layout should become selectable in the Windows keyboard language settings. Restart session/windows before and/or after picking it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way to set that up is actually to use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). This will allow you to create your own Keyboard Layout from scratch, or you can load preexisting layouts to modify them as you want to.